# BeautifulSoup4 in python 3 to scrape from frame & frameset

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am stuck in scraping data from website using python & beautiful soup
[html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5BlG.png)

if you check the image ( html page ) attached

i want to reach at the form (line in  blue color ) but i am unable to reach there

i tried normal parsing from frameset to form ( no success )
tried switching frame as mentioned below ( no success)

```
frame = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('frame')[1]
driver.switch_to_frame(frame)

for ch3 in soup.findAll("frame", { "name" : "bodyframe" }):
    if ch3.name=="frame":
        print(ch3.contents)
```

in the above code switch does happen but the contents of **ch3** are showing null

the problem is unable to get in the document with frame name = **bodyframe**
any suggestion how i can fetch details from form ( dark blue line )

let me know if i need give any other information

Thanks in advance

Comment: It appears that you're using Selenium to load the web page in a browser and then to manipulate it, including switching frames, but then you try to use BeautifulSoup to find items in that frame. You should use Selenium to search in the loaded frame.

Comment: after loading the frame if i see the html of that frame it is giving me null which is why i am unable to find anything.

Comment: the structure is <frameset> inside this 3 <frameset> and then each frameset is having <frame>

Comment: Responding to your first comment: When the statement `driver.switch_to_frame(frame)` is executed do you see the frame in the browser window?